# iphone uitabbar menu option rather than view

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I have a tab bar controller with 6 tabs. The 6th tab I want to simply do an action (like rate this app) and not move to a new view.

The tab bar elements need to have a view object, so is there any way I can work around this to directly call a selector which will perform an action.

EDIT:
Here is the selector I would like to call from my 6th tab and continue remain on the current view.

```
-(void)action_rateThisApp:(id)sender {

NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str]; 
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];

// Here is the app id from itunesconnect
// http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cricbuzz-cricket-scores-news/id360466413?mt=8
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@360466413", str];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the delegate function

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

To intercept the tab bar item touch. From there you can do whatever you want. You can generate the interface view you want for rating your app and add it to your main window (so that it is superimposed on the current view, whichever tab you are currently on).

Comment: I do not want to generate a view or display a different view. I only want to call an action when that particular tab is pressed, call the selector to handle it and remain on the same view.

Comment: Well in that case just ignore the second part of the answer and do whatever you need to do, in the delegate callback (the suggestion to add it to the window meant that when the user dismisses it, your app remains in the same state as it was). If you return NO in that callback it won't select the tab, which is what you want.

Comment: Sounds right. But now what would be the type of my 6th tab. Currently for the other 5 I am using "UIViewController" objects. To display the 6th option what object should I use. I creating UIViewController objects and adding to the UITabBar like "[localTabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:"",""...

Comment: You can just put an empty view controller in there which will never be used, except to check which tab has been pressed.

Comment: The callback works fine for 5 tabs but I have 6 tabs and the problem is that when the last two tabs are shown in the 'more' section then they appear in a tableview and therefore the above callback does not get called for my last tab.